# Using a predictive model on a dataset with different explanatory variables

Tags: regression, dataset

As part of an assignment, we built a logistic regression model on a training data set. The test data, however, doesn't have one of the variables that was in the training data and included in the model.

What should be done to test the model in this situation? Can we just ignore the fact that the model contains a variable that's not in the data, or do we have to accommodate for this somehow?

I'm using R, and originally planned to use the `predict()` function to test the model, but this won't be possible given the different variables between the model and the data.

Answer (score 0):

In your situation, I'd do two things:

- Test your model including this one variable by means of *cross-validation*.
- Investigate what the explanatory power of your model is in case you don't use this variable. This time I would check the performance two times, once on your test set, and once again by means of cross-validation on your training set.

Now you can compare the scores in the first and second situation. If your scores don't differ that much, perhaps you can consider building a model without using this variable. It has considerable explanatory power, I'd say I'd try to get the data on the test set for this variable as well.